# Can't compare char array vs char array of pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have some words which i stored in char array of pointer like

```
char* someWords[]={"a", "about", "above","across", "after", "afterwards",      
"again", "against", "all",
"almost", "alone", "along", "already","also","although","always","am","among"} //etc,320 words
char x[1024]; // used this to read file
```

Then i read another file and fetch the words in order to compare with someWords, if they are same, i won't count them in. I did something like this.

```
 while (fscanf(fone,"%1023s",x) == 1) { 
    i=0;


    while(i<541 && x!=someWords[i]){ //if file contains stopwords.  also tried (strcmp(x,someWords[i])!=0)

    i++;

    //printf("\n len:%d",strlen(x));

    }
    if(i==541)
    {
        printf("\n%s is not stop word ",x);   

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%s is stop word ",x);

    }
}
```

The problem is all words printed as " is not stop word" , which made me to figured out that the program can't compare  `x` and `someWords[i]`. So what should i do to fix it? Which types of variables should i use? Or should i completely changed my approach of reading file?

Comment: Well, what does x array contain - one word, or a bunch of words?  If it contains a bunch of words in one big string, you will need to parse them out somehow, then compare each one against someWords.

Comment: Where is `hashTable[i]`?

Comment: And you must indeed compare strings with the strcmp family; a pointer comparison will typically fail, as opposed to C#, where it results in a real comparison.

Comment: Unless this is an assignment, use C# anyway, it will save you a ton of work. Or one of the script languages.

Comment: @OldProgrammer x array contains bunch of words. But i think every time fscanf works, it assigns x to only one word. So that's why i compare with someWords[i]

Comment: @Gunner yes, scanf basically reads space separated text items (numbers, words).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider as this is a homework, i must do this in C.

Comment: Also i've searched for hours these pointer things and couldn't find any solution to fix. Why would one gave me negative point, i can't figure out!

Comment: Are you stepping through the code in a debugger, and looking at the values, etc?  You are not showing us what is in x, so nobody can tell you how to code this.  Please show an example of the file input.

Comment: @MikeCAT i corrected spelling

Comment: When i debug it,  `x` contains bunch of values consist of words,zeros,backslashes etc.  FYI i read the file which contains one sentence(i.e. several words separated by spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your program a bit and it works nicely. I have

- terminated the list of words with a null pointer so that we don't rely on numbers.
- used `strcmp`.
- read from `stdin` instead of from a file (the expected input is a simple series of words which may or may not match one of the stop words).
- introduced a "found" flag and a mid-loop break instead of having the comparison in the loop condition (this way we can do things if found).

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* someWords[]=
    {   "a", "about", "above","across", 
        "after", "afterwards",      
        "almost", "alone", "along", 
        "already","also","although",
        "always","am","among", 0};      //etc,320 words

char x[1024]; // used this to read file 

int main()
{
    while (scanf("%1023s",x) == 1)
    {
        int found = 0;

        for(int i=0; someWords[i]; i++)
        {   printf("%s, %s\n",someWords[i], x);
            if( strcmp(x,someWords[i])==0 )
            {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }       
        if(!found)
        {
            printf("\n%s is not stop word\n",x);   

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n%s is stop word\n",x);

        }
    }   return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -Wall -o word-arr  word-arr.c  && ./word-arr 
above lalala <-- input 
a, above 
about, above 
above, above

above is stop word 
a, lalala 
about, lalala 
above, lalala 
across, lalala 
after, lalala 
afterwards, lalala 
almost, lalala 
alone, lalala 
along, lalala 
already, lalala 
also, lalala 
although, lalala 
always, lalala 
am, lalala 
among, lalala

lalala is not stop word
```

Comment: It's working (on consecutive words) and explained  very well thank you so much! However, if some cells of my stopWords array contains NULL strings, it doesn't work. Assume my array is like that `someWords[10]=along,someWords[11]=<null>,someWords[12]=<null>,someWords[13]=already,someWords[14]=<null>` . How can i overcome this situation?

Comment: (The idea to terminate with a null pointer comes from the `argv` in `main(int argc, char **argv)` which redundantly terminates `argv` with a null pointer as well as provides a count with `argc`.) To deal with null pointers, you have two possibilities. (1) Define a stop word which cannot appear in the data. Or (2) rely on a count. It is easy to count if the words array is a true array which is known and filled at compile time (`sizeof(someWords)/sizeof(someWords[0])`); but that fails silently if someWords is just a pointer to a dynamically allocated array which is an easily conceivable change.

Answer (score 3):

To compare two strings, use `strcmp(x, someWords[i])`. The result will be 0 if they are equal.

You can't compare with `x!=someWords[i]` because this only compares the pointers, not the contents of the string.

Comment: I've already used this but as i commented out, it doesn't work

Comment: I can only comment on the code you posted. Other than the `strcmp` and the number of words to check, this code seems correct. Either you implemented `strcmp` incorrectly, or `x` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: I think `x` doesn't contain what i think it does. when i debug it i see hundreds of nonsensical values like zeros,slashes,words etc in  `x`.